# Путь к файлу через app.config

Tags: c#

Знаю как в си шарпе указать путь к файлам, но это будет работать только на моем пк, при переносе программы на другой пк путь будет другой. Как можно правильно прописать путь к файлу через app.config что бы работало на разных пк?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: а что вы уже сделали? Вас интересует как получить строку с адресом, или вам нужно внести строку с адресом, или что? Ваш вопрос слишком общий что-бы дать на него однозначный и точный ответ!

Comment: Клади файлы в общие папки по типу AppData

Comment: Есть программа которая работает с файлами, сортирует и удаляет их, на моем пк делает это по одному пути, на другой машине путь будет другой. Интересует как сделать так, что бы не прописывать каждый раз новый путь, а в этом appconfig указать универсальный доступ к этим файлам @VladimirT

Comment: Хорошо, намекну, выложите сюда файл app.config, и обработчик который у вас получает данные!

Comment: в вопрос добавьте (отредактируйте)!

Comment: @VladimirT готово

Comment: Хорошо, и кто вам мешает добавить строку <add key="DestFolder" value="C:\Моя_Папка"/>?

Comment: и еще одно, это приложение winform или wpf?

Comment: @VladimirT это обычное консольное приложение, но суть еще в том что там папка с временными файлами, а на разных пк путь будет разный из за пользователей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-е что вам нужно сделать, это добавить параметр в конфигурацию:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <startup> 
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
 </startup>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="" value=""/>
    <add key="DestFolder" value="C:\Моя_Папка"/>

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Добавляем ссылку на System.Configuration, в папке ссылки, и не забываем конечно using System.Configuration;

Далее в коде:
получение:

```
var currentConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DestFolder");
```

Задание:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("DestFolder", @"C:\Моя_Папка2");
```

Вот собственно и все что вам нужно.

Comment: куда нужно вставлять эту строчку ?:                                             `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("DestFolder", @"C:\Моя_Папка2");`

Comment: в код, где вам нужно изменить настройку, скажем, тогда когда вы в консоли указываете что собираетесь изменить настройку (как, когда и зачем, это вопрос к вашей фантазии).

Answer (score 1):

Есть возможность указать **относительный** путь к нужному файлу.

К примеру, у вас исполняемый файл называется `main.exe`. Вам, например, нужно указать путь к файлу `texture.png`, находящемуся в папке `img`. Структура решения (проекта) VS для C# будет примерно такой:

```
/MyProject
    /bin
        main.exe
    /img
        texture.png
    main.cs
```

Тогда относительный путь к файлу можно определить так:

```
String path = "..\\img\\texture.png"
```

Comment: Вообще, конфигурация для того и используется, что при компиляции она помещается в папку с исполнительным файлом, соответственно существуют уже и готовые методы для работы с ним.